# Is Psalm 74:10 referencing a generic enemy or a specific one?

Tags: psalms

```
        Psalm 74:10
```

O God, how long shall the adversary reproach? Shall the enemy blaspheme thy name for ever?

> Is the psalmist addressing a generic enemy or a specific one?

Answer (score 1):

[thehistoryville](https://www.thehistoryville.com/nebuchadnezzar-destroyed-jerusalem/) says:

> In December 589 B.C., Nebuchadnezzar, the King of Babylon, invaded
> Jerusalem and began a siege against King Zedekiah of Judah and the
> inhabitants of Jerusalem. The siege lasted for more than a year as the
> Jews endured the effects of the blockade. Morality among the Jews
> plummeted as famine set in and because of their poor state, various
> plagues began to afflict them.

[image]

- Psalm 74:10 appears to address a specific enemy who reproaches and blasphemies God's name
- The psalmist pleads with God to remember His covenant promises and act on behalf of His people in the face of their enemies
- Lamentation in the psalm is a lamentation over the destruction of the temple in Jerusalem and the absence of God's intervention to defend His people

Let me [add](https://www.moon.com/travel/arts-culture/jerusalem-history-first-second-temples/#:%7E:text=During%20the%20First%20Temple%20period,Babylon%2C%20when%20he%20conquered%20Jerusalem.):

> During the First Temple period (1200-586 BC), the First Temple was
> built in 1000 BC by King Solomon after King David conquered Jerusalem
> and made it his capital. **The Temple was destroyed in 586 BC by
> Nebuchadnezzar**, the King of Babylon, when he conquered Jerusalem.

This [here](https://davidschrock.com/2019/06/13/the-historical-background-of-psalm-74-75-a-case-for-reading-psalms-with-1-2-chronicles/#:%7E:text=Many%20commentators%20place%20the%20%E2%80%9Ctemple,plausible%20for%20an%20earlier%20reading.) poses a possible different timing:

> From this reading, Psalms 74–75 find a historical connection in
> **Shisak’s invasion** recorded in 2 Chronicles 10–12 (ca. **930 BC**).

> Many commentators place the “temple-smashing” description of Psalm 74
> at the **Babylonian destruction** of the temple (ca. **586 BC**). Surely, the
> later dating is plausible, but in my reading the textual evidence is
> equally, if not more, plausible for an earlier reading.

From [here:](https://www.easyenglish.bible/psalms/psalm074-taw.htm)

> Psalm 74 is about when **Nebuchadnezzar destroyed** the *temple. The
> *psalmist asks God to think again! "Keep your promise" in verse 20 is "remember the *covenant" in *Hebrew. The *covenant was when God and
> the *Israelites agreed. God would *protect them if they obeyed him.
> The trouble was that they did not obey him. So God let Nebuchadnezzar
> destroy the *temple. He also took the *Israelites to Babylon. There
> they had to do what he told them to do. They were in *exile. Really,
> they were in a prison a long way from home.
>
> Psalm 74 tells us what Nebuchadnezzar did to the *temple. The
> *Israelites were sorry because Nebuchadnezzar destroyed the *temple. They were not sorry that they had *disobeyed God. ("*Disobeyed" means
> "did not obey".) That is why God did not have to keep his promise. So
> he let Nebuchadnezzar and his army destroy the *temple.

- "Adversary" and "enemy" are specific words and likely refer to historical adversaries of Israel who have attacked and desecrated the sanctuary of God. Psalm 74:3:

> Lift up Your feet to the perpetual desolations. The enemy has damaged
> everything in the sanctuary.

- This could be literal or allegorical. The enemy represents the forces of evil and opposition that seek to undermine God's purposes and faith in His people.

Answer (score 1):

In context this Psalm refers to a specific collective enemy of God. This is clear from the context.

> 4 Your foes roared triumphantly in the place of your assembly;
> they set up their own tokens of victory. 5 They hacked away like a forester gathering boughs,
> swinging his ax in a thicket of trees. 6 They smashed all its engraved work,
> struck it with ax and pick. 7 They set your sanctuary on fire,
> profaned your name’s abode by razing it to the ground.

If this is truly a psalm of Asaph, then it hard to place the historical events referred to, since Asaph lived during the reigns of David and Solomon; and the sanctuary did not experience any such catastrophe in those years. Thus, either Asaph was speaking prophetically or the attribution (by a later editor) is mistaken. As @Jason points out, the psalm fits especially well with the fate of the Temple during the early stages of the Babylonian exile. The Temple was plundered on [other occasions](https://www.biblestudy.org/maps/attacks-on-jerusalem-timeline.html), but the Babylonian armies are the most likely candidate.

Nevertheless, psalms are often interpreted allegorically and personally, in which case the adversary would be Satan.

**Conclusion**: The psalmist speaks of a specific collective enemy, probably the forces of the Babylonian Empire. However, readers often interpret the psalms allegorically, as referring to their personal struggle against God's ancient adversary.

Comment: @ Dan Fefferman Thanks Dan. Actually it was your reference in my previous question that caused me to notice this. Anytime I see adversary or enemy I consider Satin ( adversary) as the possible meaning. Because Psalms has many duel meaning to David's time as well as the future events, I wondered if some hermeneutic might give an answer.